# How can we show success message on signup page of verify gmail account in django and bootstrap?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-views, django-templates

I have been able to successfully register an account using Django, but am having issues displaying success messages to verify the email account. I am using Django and Bootstrap for my project, and am seeking guidance on how to display and style these messages. When attempting to return the messages, I am encountering an error. Could you please provide assistance on how to properly display and handle these messages?

```
accounts/views.py 

class SignUp(CreateView,SuccessMessageMixin):
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
        
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False # Deactivate account till it is confirmed
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your Believer Account'
            message = render_to_string('accounts/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            success_registered_message = "You're register successfully"
            verify_message = "Please verify your account from gmail"
            return success_registered_message,verify_message

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

templates/accounts/signup.html

{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

if more details are require then tell in a comments. I'll update my question with that information. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Django has a framework for messages, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/. Thus those messages could be send to the framework. After the successful POST you could redirect to a (or same) view which allows the rendering of the message and the user seeing your content with a GET.

Comment: I have tried this too, and read this documentation but i did not understand much ,that's why i asked this question , can you please tell me how can i correct my code and make messages workable in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i don't want to redirect on any other page, i just want to stay on they same page (register page) and want to show message after successfully registration.

What you want with websites is a Post-Redirect-Get pattern. You can some background  here: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post
It's possible to redirect to the same view, if want to land on the same view/template.

About my suggestion about the messages framework. Hereby your code updated to work with that framework.

```
from django import http
from django.contrib import messages

class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
        
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False # Deactivate account till it is confirmed
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your Believer Account'
            message = render_to_string('accounts/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            messages.success(
                request,
                "You're register successfully. Please verify your account "
                "from gmail"
            )
            return http.HttpResponseRedirect('<your-url>')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

This should work with what you added to your template.

Furthermore, make sure your settings contain the following things:

- 'django.contrib.messages' is in INSTALLED_APPS.
- MIDDLEWARE contains 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' and 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'.
- The default storage backend relies on sessions. That’s why SessionMiddleware must be enabled and appear before MessageMiddleware in MIDDLEWARE.
- The 'context_processors' option of the DjangoTemplates backend defined in your TEMPLATES setting contains 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'.

Comment: The settings which BlackEagle52 outlined above, should be already set up by default when starting project using newest version of django.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views

The **SuccessMessageMixin** has an attribute **success_message**, which should be updated in your case to;

**success_message** = "You're registered successfully, Please verify your account from gmail"

You should also redirect to the desired page, or render the current page if needed

Comment: ```success_message = "You're registered successfully, Please verify your account from gmail"
            success_message = "You're registered successfully, Please verify your account from gmail"
            return render(request,self.template_name)``` , i update my account by this but this didn't work.

Comment: i don't want to redirect on any other page , i just want to stay on they same page (register page) and want to show message after successfully registration.